# Redirect Certain Requests

Tags: configuration, redirect

I setup my linux server to be used as a DNS server. I'm trying to figure out how I can redirect requests to a certain URL. For example, `site1.com` is requested. The server takes the request, and changes it to `site2.com`, so the data is received from `site2.com` rather than `site1.com`. How can I do this? Example:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name site1.com
location / {
proxy_pass http://site1.com/;
proxy_set_header host $http_host;
resolver 8.8.8.8;
}
    -Get Data from site2.com-
}
```

The server returns a .json file, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think we're confusing something here, you say DNS then show an excerpt from an Nginx config which does nothing with DNS....

are you wanting to redirect the user (which you mention) or reverse proxy which is how you've started the config ?

Comment: A server makes a request through the server. I want to redirect it to another site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx

Answer (score 0):

You could proxy the other site, if you wanted to, but really you should issue a 302 redirect if you want that to happen.  This will cause the user's browser to request data directly from the other site.